# Gcc exit status codes

Tags: gcc

I've noticed that when running gcc, if the compile failes, most of the time it returns an exit status code of '1'.  However, it sometimes returns a status code of '4' (for example, if the input file does not exist).  I haven't been able to find anything in the gcc documentation that covers what different error codes might mean -- does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-pass-exit-codes) of the command line switch `-pass-exit-codes`:

> Normally the gcc program exits with the code of 1 if any phase of the compiler returns a non-success return code. If you specify -pass-exit-codes, the gcc program instead returns with the numerically highest error produced by any phase returning an error indication. The C, C++, and Fortran front ends return 4 if an internal compiler error is encountered.

Comment: So the documentation seems to be wrong -- it sometimes returns a non-1 error exit code even without this option, and the error of a missing input file is certainly not an internal compiler error.

Comment: Which gcc version are you using? My gcc version 7.3.0 and an old gcc 4.0.0 both return 1 when the given file does not exist.

Comment: I have "gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)", and it returns 4 if you run it with no input files (e.g., just "gcc" on the command line)

Comment: So it's not that a file does not exist, it's that there's no input files specified on the command line.